# Can we still consider that Moore's law still holds true regarding the consequence on CPU speed?

Tags: computer-science, cpu, speed

Moore's law is an empirical law and in simple terms states that the number of transistors on integrated circuits doubles approximately every two years.

One of the consequences of Moore's law is that CPU performance doubles every 18 Months.

I've seen 'Why is Moore's Law seen as an absolute truth?' and although curious does not answer my question.

Currently we are partly achieving that by making multi core CPU's.

**Can we still consider that speed of CPU's doubles every 18 months?**

Multi-core CPU's can be looked at just as distributed computing. A "good old" single threaded sofware/algorithm won't be able to take full advantage of such CPU as before and It's not true that all algorithms are paralelizable with speed gain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is Moore's Law seen as an absolute truth?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/205865/why-is-moores-law-seen-as-an-absolute-truth)

Comment: @gnat - I am not asking if it's an absolute true. Moore's law is called law but it's an empirical assumption from several facts. From a physics perspective it's clear that is not possible forever. I am asking if nowadays this law can still be looked as valid considering we're building multi-core CPU's

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not

Comment: From the assumptions (1) "the number of transistors on integrated circuits grows" and (2) "CPU speed ~ no. of transistors" you infer that "CPU speed stalls" implies "Moore's law does not hold". But it's statement (2) that is wrong, regardless of whether you take "speed" to mean "performance" or "clock speed".

Comment: @delnan CPU speed/performance is related with nr of transistors but not only. I used Moore law more as an introduction/context to my question. The goal to understand what is currently happening and how other developers see the nr of CPU on the context of "CPU performance".

Comment: Indium antimonide based chips and 3D transistors will be the standard CPU by 2017. These processors operate at over 2x the speed of silicon processors with the same power usage. Don't fight the law, because the law always wins.

Answer (score 3):

Processors now scale *out,* not *up;*  we are now fulfilling Moore's Law, not by adding more transistors, but by adding more cores with the same number of transistors in each one.   This is an unavoidable consequence of transistor density: clock speed has an effective (if soft) upper limit; the number of transistors you can put in the same core is constrained by heat effects and circuit leakage.

This has had implications throughout the programming community.  It means that we no longer think in terms of a single processor doing multiple tasks, but rather multiple processors doing single (and sometimes multiple tasks).

The pressure to take advantage of multiple cores has significantly influenced language design and programming techniques.  Where we would originally had been satisfied with a stateful program utilizing mutable objects, we now look more favorably on techniques involving functional programming and immutable data.

Does this answer your question?  Maybe not. But the trend to multiple cores is not going away; as programmers, *this* is what we need to be concerned about, not raw clock speed or how many transistors a die has.

Comment: 3D transistors, none-silicon base processors, stacked transistors and let's not forgot about Google's new quantum computer. AMD sells a 32-core processor now. When I read the above question it sounded like the op thought the Law has stalled somehow. That is simply not true. The problem is people want smaller tech toys now. If you look at the speed race taking place on mobile. It's the Law all over again....

Comment: I am not concerned at all. Multiple cores are there and that's a fact. I was just curious to what others think about it regarding the empirical law that states that CPU double speed every 18 months. Regarding multiple cores and programming languages. I disagree. It's not new at all. Just got more attention now due to multi-core architectures, but it's been available for long.

Comment: But you *do see my point, right?*  Anyone who is fixated on Moore's law, or whether it will still be valid 5 years from now, has taken their eye off the ball.  I daresay that those who rely on the law to get their bloated software and websites to work properly have also taken their eye off the ball.

Comment: Sure I do. But my point is if, I had to answer my own question, no - joining CPU's is not a new thing. Distributed systems either mutiple computers, or multiple CPU's in a computer are a reality for long time. What's new on this aproach is that you have 1 modules that you call multicore CPU with multiple CPU's inside. In computing though the sum of parts is not equal to the total.